# Clarification of What is Happening in Python For Loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am working through the Coursera Python course and am a bit turned around with some shorthand.

```
    x = 0
    y = 1
    for i in range(40):
    x, y = y, x + y
    print y
```

I understand it is adding X and Y and assigning the new value to Y but don't quite follow the x, y = y, x + y notation. I searched the docs without much success.

Comment: See the section [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) about the multiple assignment.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that `for`-loop isn't going to do anything due to the syntax errors (no indention on at least the assignment line, but maybe also on the final `print` statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `comma` indicates that the right hand side is a tuple containing `y` and `x+y`. The `comma` on the left indicates that the unpacking should be done.

So `x` gets the value of `y` and `y` gets the value of `x+y`

You can check how the references change simultaneously [here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=x+%3D+2%0Ay+%3D+4%0Ax,+y+%3D+y,+x+%2B+y%0Aprint+x%0Aprint+y&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D)

After opening the link, click on `visual execution` and keep clicking on `forward`.

Comment: Thanks a ton, @SilentMonk! That was very helpful. The functionality made sense but the syntax with the '=' in the middle was throwing me off. Visualizing it really helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
x, y = y, x + y
```

x is assigned the value of y
and y is assigned the value of x + y

Answer (score 0):

This assigns y to x and x+y to y, but notice that it does it at the "same time". If you tried something like

```
x = y
y = x + y
print y
```

you would get an entirely different result.

Answer (score 0):

This feature called [`sequence packing\unpacking`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). It consist of two parts: packing expression of right side near `=` sign and then unpacking it into variables from the right.

> The statement `t = 12345, 54321, 'hello!'` is an example of tuple packing: the values `12345`, `54321` and `'hello!'` are packed together in a tuple. The reverse operation is also possible:

```
x, y, z = t
```

> This is called, appropriately enough, sequence unpacking and works for any sequence on the right-hand side. Sequence unpacking requires the list of variables on the left to have the same number of elements as the length of the sequence. Note that multiple assignment is really just a combination of tuple packing and sequence unpacking.